# how to create a Time Bar Chart in android

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to create Time bar Like attached Image.
Color of Time Bar can change according to Time

if busy Time Is 8:30-9:45am

it should display on Time bar in color like below in image

[image]

Comment: Use a charting library, such as [aChartEngine](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)

Comment: Der I m Getting My Solution i know This Is achartEngin But How To

Answer (score 1):

You can use horizontal bar chart with following settings..

```
  GraphicalView mChart;
  XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

  multiRenderer.setOrientation(org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.Orientation.VERTICAL);


  mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context,
                    dataset, multiRenderer, Type.STACKED);
```